# How to remove "Migration Failed" message from SBS 2011

Tags: windows-sbs-2011, migration

I have successfully completed the migration from SBS 2003 to SBS 2011. The migration process stopped halfway done.

I found out that I had a corrupted info.xml

Following the instructions [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2533423) seemed to fix everything except the message "How do I recover from a failed installation?"

[image]

This screen comes up everytime I log in, and reboot does not fix it.

So the question is, How do I remove it?

Comment: These two statements contradict each other: "I have successfully completed the migration from SBS 2003 to SBS 2011. The migration process stopped halfway done."

Comment: Seems pretty clear from the message here that you have to continue the reinstallation process and your server is still somewhat in limbo, but maybe I haven't dug into this enough.

Comment: @joeqwerty I know, that's why I'm so puzzled. I have no errors in the errorlog. And no errors were reported during the migration process. As stated the process stopped, and was restarted following microsofts instructions on provided link. After that everything worked fine. Except for this screen that keeps reappearing.

Comment: @BrentPabst I disagree, the server has been in production mode for several weeks and the old server has been discontinued. Everything is working fine, including Exchange/Sharepoint. We have gone through the log files and found nothing out of the ordinary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution.

Using `msconfig` and `regedit` to disable and delete the command running the helpfile.

[image: msconfig]
[image: regedit]